# How to prevent hyperlink from triggering intent filter on android?

Tags: android, twitter, web-applications

I have a hyperlink on a web page that submit a tweet to Twitter.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=This is a tweet">Tweet</a>
```

On Android, it prompts the user to choose between the Twitter app (if installed) or the web browser. Is there a way to force android to send the tweet using the web browser. In other words, I don't want the user to be prompted whether he wants to send the tweet using the Twitter app or the web browser. I want web browser only. Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should be able to do this by overriding some methods of the webClient that you are providing.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // do your implementation here, by checking the url and what you want to do with it...
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // page started loading
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // page finished loading
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Rex, thank you for the input, but the hyperlink is simple HTML in a web page show in a web browser, not in a web view. Any idea?

Comment: Oops...AFAIK that is just platform dependent thing...no clue

Answer (score 0):

> On Android, it prompts the user to choose between the Twitter app (if installed) or the web browser.

That depends on the Web browser. There are many Web browsers for Android. The behavior, when the browser encounters a link like this, is up to the browser developers. Some browsers will show a chooser; some browsers will keep the link within the browser.

> Is there a way to force android to send the tweet using the web browser.

No, because Android has nothing to do with it. Web browser developers can do what they want. If they want to start an activity with an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` and thereby trigger the chooser (or go straight to the app, on Android 6.0+ for apps that use app links), that is up to the browser developers, not you.